# Wordpress dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, wordpress

I have an issue creating array out of post title => post url values (of custom post type).

```
global $wp_query;
$type = 'qa';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$array = ();  
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      $title = get_the_title();
      $url = get_the_permalink();
      $data[] = array('key1'=>$title, 'key2'=>$url);
}
```

I tried this and couple other combinations but without too much luck.

End result I would like to have dynamic array that I'm able to search with ajax in jQuery.

That part is working with static array but I can't manage to get it dynamic and working.

Exact format I need to get is:

```
$data = array(
 "Post 1 title" => "link post 1",
 "Post 2 title" => "link post 2",
 "Post 3 title" => "link post 3"
);
```

Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is incomplete. You are trying to build your array **before** you are actually starting the loop. You need to move everything **inside** the loop and then build your array.

Just a tip, because you are using a custom post type, rather use [`get_post_permalink`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_permalink) to get the post permalink

```
$type = 'qa';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

$data = array();
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      $title = get_the_title();
      $url = get_post_permalink();
      $data[$title] = $url;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
var_dump( $data );
```

Comment: Hi Pieter. Yes, I realized that and it is working now. Many thanks and to others as well for help!

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
global $wp_query;
$type = 'qa';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$data = array();  
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      $title = get_the_title();
      $url = get_the_permalink();
      $data[$title] = $url;
}
```